# Windows 8 App Add-on to visual studio 2012 for desktop

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, windows-phone-8

The title pretty much says it all. I've downloaded Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop but I also want to be able to develop apps for Windows 8.

Rather than having to download another version of Visual studio (Visual Studio 2012 **for Windows 8**). Isn't there just a way to add add-ons on my current VS to enable developing for Windows 8?

Thanks in advance!

PS - If there's an add-on to develop for Windows PHONE 8 that will also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe you need to be on windows 8 to develop for windows 8

Comment: @dougajmcdonald - Hey Doug, I am indeed running Windows 8 :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop windows 8 phone, you still can use VS 2012 express, but you must install windows 8 phone SDK, you can download it here http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk.

But if you want to develop desktop app with VS 2012 Express, Unfortunately you can't, but IMHO you can still use csharp compiler in command line to do that. but you must references all the library you use in your app. to be honest I never try it, CMIIW.

Cheer
Yusak Setiawan
http://apptivate.ms/apps/1271/mathboard

Comment: Thanks for your reply! What would then be the only way to develop Windows 8 desktop apps? Thanks.